# Is Stack Overflow for Teams good for external users?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Is Stack Overflow for Teams a good solution for a community forum for customers of a SaaS product to interact among themselves, or is it more for internal users?

Comment: I wonder if Discourse would be better - one of the Stack Overflow founders was involved in the development of that product, and it is open source.

Answer (score 7):

The [Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) product is sold with per-user license fees, which means that it requires a defined membership of users. The same licensing model is used for [Stack Overflow Enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise). As such, I would not think that these are well-suited for an external-facing support platform.

However, Yaakov Ellis suggests (below in the comments) that this is a use-case that some clients are exploring. I would recommend that you reach out to a Stack Overflow salesperson to see if there is a way to make one of these products work for your application.

Comment: Stack Overflow [Enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise) and [Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) both require license fees per user. Either could be an excellent solution for a community forum, depending on the specific needs. This is definitely a use-case that some of our clients are exploring and the product can be very effective at this (we have a Team for all Stack Moderators which is similar to this use case). I will leave it to someone more familiar with the product to give a canonical answer to this one.

Comment: Please be sure to ping me when that happens; I will be happy to delete this. Or, of course, the team member who answers can also delete this answer, as they see fit, if they have such privileges. I don't think that the Stack Moderators Team is a very good example, though. The moderator roster doesn't change *that* frequently, not nearly as often as new folks would want support for a product. Maybe if your product was *also* licensed, and then you would just grant access to a private Team for support as part of the product license?

Comment: @CodyGray I just posted an answer below for how Business and Enterprise in fact, do get used for this purpose already. Hope that clarifies things!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) is a solution that can be used as a support forum for customers. We have existing customers that do so already and like it because all activity is behind a login wall and limits membership to their customer accounts.

This is a special set up that requires the [Business or Enterprise tier](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/pricing) (not the Basic tier). Additionally our Customer Success team helps get this up and running and provides ongoing guidance and support.

[Here's some more information](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/use-cases/customer-support) about using Teams for customer support.  If you'd like to learn more, we definitely recommend reaching out to our [Sales team](https://stackoverflow.com/business/get-started) and setting up some time to talk.

Comment: How do I, as a customer or potential customer, get access to this login-restricted Team? Having to request access adds a *substantial* barrier to entry, not only reducing the quality of the experience for me as the customer (probably resulting in me going elsewhere and the company losing a sale), and also increases the overhead for the company offering the support service. Now there’s an extra step each time, and a lot more latency, meaning your support quality is reduced by one of the most common metrics.

Comment: Additionally, your answer doesn’t explain how cost is determined. I realize this might be able to be negotiated on a case-by-case basis, but it should be something you can speak to generally. Does the company have to pay for each user who has access to the support forum? If so, that could get very expensive. What about disabling access? How do you decide when to disable a customer’s access to your paywalled support forum, so that you can stop paying a monthly fee for them? Or are you stuck paying for them effectively forever? (Great for SO, bad for the company who uses it.)

Comment: Great questions! So far, most requests we've received and fulfilled subsequently have been good with the login restricted setup - our SSO integration and SCIM support helps take care of account deactivation without any manual client intervention. We are however always watching out and listening for customer / prospect requests that then very directly chart the features we work on - like removing the login wall barrier could very well be one in the future.

Comment: On the second question, you are right, every package is built on a case-by-case basis and negotiated, hence I am unable to go into the specifics too much. It depends as much on the use case as it does on the set up.

Comment: So...it sounds like Teams doesn't actually work for the use-case that is described here. The only answer you can give is "contact sales, we might be able to help", which isn't helpful nor does it answer the question. It is always possible to *make* something work if one is sufficiently motivated, but that doesn't mean it is a good fit.